# How change the global tint color in Xamarin forms of the iOS application?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I change the global tint color of my iOS app in a Xamarin forms project (C#)?

Answer (score 4):

The global iOS tint color can be set via [`UIApplication.KeyWindow`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UIApplication.KeyWindow/) when it becomes available, the earliest after the application finished launching:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            var result = base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);

            uiApplication.KeyWindow.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;

            return result; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change the color of buttons or pickers. Is there an automatic way for those to pick up the global tint?

Answer (score -1):

Add following code in your applications finished launching method in Xamarin.iOS Project.

```
Boolean result = base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.TintColor = UIColor.Green;
return result;
```

Comment: What should I fill in the <IDSA_Style> for a green color for example? I don't know the syntax... @Abhimanyu

Comment: Downvoted for the unexplained inclusion of a DependencyService in what should really be a very simple example.

Comment: UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.TintColor = UIColor.Green;

Comment: This worked for me, at least it changed the color of my checkmark in a UITableView of my spike app where I was testing this snippet.